# Process.Start() wont start the process correctly

Tags: c#, process, subdirectory, process.start

Im making a small loader for the game PSOBB but for the offline version, im lazy to go in a folder called "servers" and launch all 3 server executable files, so thats y im making this program. So my problem is that i made a button that launches the .exe from another folder (a sub dir).

```
private void startLoginServerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] killLoginServer = Process.GetProcessesByName("login_server");

    if (killLoginServer.Length == 0)
    {
        Process.Start("servers\\login_server.exe");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        refresh(); // This goes to another method and checks if the program is running
    }
    else if (killLoginServer.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (Process stop in killLoginServer)
        {
            stop.Kill();
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        refresh();
    }
}
```

it checks if the process is running or not and if its not it launches it. the problem is that when i press the button, it start BUT it doesn't load completely, so then it closes, but if i start the process manually, it works fine. I tried running my loader as Administrator but nothing... i even tried specifying the full path but the problem still there.

Comment: Are these executables on the same machine or in a remote folder share?

Comment: Poorly written programs usually don't work well if you don't set the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory.  That tends to crash and burn them if they use a relative path name to load a file.  Like you do in your code snippet.  Be sure to set the WorkingDirectory to the same path as the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

your path is wrong..

you must fully qualify that path when starting any process found in that location. see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)

in your pc : `Process.Start("C:\\myprocess.exe");`

in other pc : `Process.Start("OtherPcNetAddress\\SharedFolder\\myprocess.exe");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your path is correct. You either need to specify an absolute path like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:/servers/login_server.exe");
```

Or a relative path like this:

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"servers/login_server.exe"));
```

Comment: still doesnt work. the program im trying to load is a console based program. the console window opens for a split second and then it closes. does that for all programs im trying to open :/